# Files copied from one NTFS disk to another are not visible, but only on one machine

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs

I used my Win10 desktop to copy data from my NTFS disk to a new one (where Windows 10 was already installed). I copied just some files, and not a while partition. I've put the files in `c:\data`.

Then I've put the new disk in my laptop. My laptop can see everything on the new disk (operating system, programs I installed previously). But it doesn't see `c:\data`!

I've put the disk back into my desktop - `c:\data` is visible.
I've put it into my laptop again - `c:\data` is not visible!

"Show hidden files, folders and drives" is enabled, "Hide protected operating system files" is disabled. I can see all of those `c:\$Recycle.Bin`, `c:\hiberfil.sys` and everything else. But not `c:\data`.
I've also did an extended scan of the disk (using Samsung Magician) - it reported the disk is healthy.

Any ideas what could be happening?

Answering questions from comments:

- My user is local admin.
- After running `explorer.exe` using admin permissions `c:\data` is still not visible.
  In `cmd` (also as admin) `dir` doesn't display it either.
- Disk is connected using SATA III.
- `cd c:\data` and `attrib c:\data` result in `File not found` (in `cmd` run as admin).

Comment: Is your laptop user account that of administrator? Try [How to Run Windows 11 File Explorer as Administrator](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/run-windows-11-file-explorer-as-administrator/) and if `c:\data` is now visible check its permissions.

Comment: How was the disk connected?

Comment: From a CMD terminal can you change into the folder?  CD C:\DATA
Can you get attributes for the folder from a CDM prompt?  ATTTRIB C:\DATA